# Snowflake + Python Dataframe To_SQL Error

Tags: python, snowflake-schema

[image]

When I try to insert a dataframe into my snowflake database, i receive this error. I have checked the connections and privileges, I am able to create tables, but it is only this is not working.

DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': not all arguments converted during string formatting